# makebst but show url only if there is no doi

Tags: bibtex, urls, doi, custom-bib

I am using `makebst` to create my own bib style. 
I would like the DOI to show up in the citation (as a hyperlink), whenever the DOI is present. I have successfully done that.
When the DOI is present, I do NOT want the `URL` field to be used, since that is often redundant or pointless. I therefore disabled using the `URL` field in `makebst`.
However, when there is no `DOI` field (some journals, etc. that I have do not have a DOI), I would like the `URL` field to appear instead. There is no option for this in makebst (as far as I can tell).

So, how can I use my `makebst` made `bst` file and use DOI preferentially, but URL when no DOI is present.

Packages I am using that might have an impact: `hyperref`, `cite`, `url`.
[I am not using `biblatex`, which causes some other problems for me.]

Comment: You have to modify manually the resulting `bst` file. Unless, you have to submit the paper to publications still using bibtex, it would much easier to use `biblatex` (and to solve the other issue you might have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the makebst output bst file, I found the following works. It amounts to changing the doi format. Make sure to first tell makebst to NOT include url (the default option).

1. Open the .bst file (the makebst output)
2. In the ENTRY section (the first section not commented out for me), you'll see a bunch of fields, including doi. Add 'url' (without the quotes) to this list.
3. Go to the line that says FUNCTION {format.doi}. The next line should say { "" }. At least, that's what I had. Now, replace the { "" } with the following block of code:

   ```
       { url empty$
           { "" }
           {
             new.block
             "\url{" url * "}" *
           }
         if$
       }
   ```

After doing step 3, my format.doi block looks as follows (but yours might differ if you selected different makebst options):

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { url empty$
        { "" }
        {
          new.block
          "\url{" url * "}" *
        }
      if$
    }
    {
      new.block
      "\doi{" doi * "}" *
    }
  if$
}
```